# Convert from Queue to Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, queue

I want to change a queue containing numbers and operators into an ArrayList. I am coding in Java.

Currently my Queue is defined as follows:

```
Queue outputQueue = new LinkedList();
```

The queue currently contains the following data:

```
[1, 9, 3, /, 4, 3, -, 2, /, *, +]
```

I wish to do this mainly so i can use RPN to calculate the result of the calculation, and i need to be able to index elements in the array/

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: -1 for posting it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

`List list1 = (List) outputQueue;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) When i do this, i fi try to index the newly created list like list1[2] i get an error saying "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List" Could you advise on this